# I do not receive Yahoo Account Key on my mobile number

Tags: yahoo-mail

I did not receive the account key to my Yahoo mail. Usually, I receive but recently I did not. I have access to my mobile number but the message with account key never comes even after the page says to input the account key sent to my mobile number.

I do not have a recovery email for the account just my mobile number.

Comment: You should receive it wait for some time.I have experienced same issue with yahoo. If you can try to install Yahoo mail on your phone.This way you will not require the key.